# How do I convert a combined PEM into a pkcs12 P12 file?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pem, pkcs#12, apns-sharp

I have an Apple Push Notification Service PEM file which I have working in a PHP script. I can send push notifications to iOS devices that have my app installed. I am trying to make it work with the APNS-Sharp project in my Mono environment. The APNS-Sharp library requires a PKCS12 P12 file and all I have is the PEM which has the certificate and the key combined.

How do I get my PKCS12 file from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate